# How to copy VirtualBox VDI file

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, files, vdi

I had an old PC with Lubuntu 18.04 installed.

I installed VirtualBox in order to have Windows XP (as a virtual machine)

During a Lubuntu update to 18.10 the whole system crashed. Before i reinstal Lubuntu I tried to copy VDI file (Virtual Drive of Win XP) in order to avoid reinstalling and setting Win XP again (it took me days to make it fully working)

I start the PC with a Ubuntu on a DVD, but when I try to copy VDI file, a message apears telling me that I 'm not the owner of the file and the copyng is rejected.

Is there any otherway to copy this file?

I have hardly any technical knowledge about Linux. I use it only with via the graphic interface

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 is EOL & thus a 'upgrade' to it makes little sense, 18.10 also upgrades to 19.04 which reaches EOL next month.  18.10 means the 2018-October (*year.month* format for releases) and you need to release-upgrade every 6-9 months which is why it's close to 19.04's end-time. If you don't like *release-upgrading* why not stick on LTS or long-term-support cycle?  As for your copy, elevate privilieges using `sudo cp`

Comment: You mention the Lubuntu 18.04 to 18.10; yes it's possible to upgrade (*I did it myself*) but it's not supported and in my opinion you should not have done it.  Please read https://lubuntu.me/cosmic-released/ or the release notes; there were problems in doing it thus the *it's unsupported*.  "*The most major and notable problem is that upgrading Lubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10 causes a fair amount of issues. Therefore, we are not officially supporting this upgrade path at this time*"   You need to be able to deal with the issues to do it.  A re-install was recommended, you could re-install to 19.10

Comment: Lubuntu chnged desktops (LXDE in 18.04 & before, LXQt in 18.10 and later) thus the difficulties...  Read the release notes, as I would have said avoid that upgrade in your case as difficulties were known, documented (there are pages on how to deal with some of them, but rather hidden as they gave people confidence to deal with it when they weren't really capable). Personally I'd suggest restore a backup and returning to 18.04 LTS which has support until 2021-April (3 years).

Comment: I didn't know that before I tried the update. I was misleaded to that by an automated message prompting me to do ;it.  However I'd like to keep 18.04 becase the PC is very old and weak and I think it cannot operate well with newer GUI.  My only concern is how to copy these files before reinstaling 18.04

Comment: I'm reluctant to provide more, 18.10 reached EOL back in July and so you could **not** have been offered any updates to 18.10 since July, so something is  (or was already) amiss  (*if you were to update since July, it'd be 19.04 not 18.10*), OR you're trying to fix a problem that occurred months ago. Either way I don't have all the details and what I have is flawed, thus unwilling to provide more.  I'd restore your backups.  *FYI: I tested 18.10 & 19.04 on single-core 1GB ram laptops but would never have used vbox on those things*

Comment: Yes, the update was performed months ago. But its now that i needed this old computer again. My concern is not the version of Lubuntu that I will install, but how to recover VirtualBox files. But it seems to be difficult, so I 'll make a clean installation again/ Anyway, thank you for the answers.

Comment: Rather than a clean install; I'd use '*something-else*' on Lubuntu 18.04, select your existing partitions and ensure you have "format" **unchecked** so it'll use your existing partitions. It will note your added packages, erase system directories (not touching your user files UNLESS you select format), then install, add-back your additional packages, then request reboot.  As long as you don't format & use existing partitions - it'll not touch user data. In modern Lubuntu - it's referred to as *Manual Partitioning* but is *Something-Else* in Lubuntu 18.04.